# docker wsl2 context missing

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows, wsl2

I installed docker desktop and wsl2 on my windows machine
At some point, i added a remote docker context and set it as default context.
Now I can't see my local wsl2 context anymore.

[image]

Here is my docker desktop configuration

[image]

And my Wsl config

[image]

How can I add a wsl docker context now it's gone ?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, here's the output from my `docker context inspect default` (on WSL2 with Docker Desktop):

```
[
    {
        "Name": "default",
        "Metadata": {
            "StackOrchestrator": "swarm"
        },
        "Endpoints": {
            "docker": {
                "Host": "unix:///var/run/docker.sock",
                "SkipTLSVerify": false
            }
        },
        "TLSMaterial": {},
        "Storage": {
            "MetadataPath": "\u003cIN MEMORY\u003e",
            "TLSPath": "\u003cIN MEMORY\u003e"
        }
    }
]
```

Not sure, but maybe you can recreate it with `docker context create --default-stack-orchestrator swarm --docker host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock default`?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have the `DOCKER_HOST` env-var set, and the `default` context is picking that up.

If you delete the `DOCKER_HOST` env-var, the `default` profile's endpoint should go back to its default value, `npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine`.

If you want to keep using `DOCKER_HOST`, you could also create a new context for Docker Desktop, copied from default while `DOCKER_HOST` is not set, and then use that context for Docker Desktop, and the `default` profile when you want to use whatever `DOCKER_HOST` points at.